# CSS element locator

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

How do i find the CSS locator to find the text "26 Todman Ave Kensington"

When I do dd:class='.pickup.ng-binding' I get the above along with the line below which contains date and time.

I need to get only Line 1[image]

Comment: Do you mean "selector," rather than "locator"? And why is this tagged as `java`?

Comment: You may be looking for the non-existent `contains` or `has` pseudo-classes.

Comment: What is the meaning of the syntax `dd:class='.pickup.ng-binding'`? It's a syntax error and will select nothing at all.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but it could be useful to learn correct terminology. CSS does not have "locators", it has "selectors".

Comment: @Justin Lardinois: Probably because OP is using Java with Selenium WebDriver, which for some reason they completely neglected to mention directly in this question. Looking at their profile, their activity in the Selenium tags seems to confirm this.

Comment: @torazaburo: The term "locator" is used in Selenium WebDriver for finding elements. It doesn't help that Selenium inaccurately uses the term "CSS" to refer to what is more specifically a CSS selector, resulting in phrases like "CSS locator" (this may also explain the use of the [css] tag - this question does not involve the use of CSS at all).

Answer (score 1):

According to your markup (and if I understand you correctly), this is the selector that you would need:

`.pickup.ng-binding > i:first-of-type`

Right now, you're selecting everything in `.pickup.ng-binding'`. What you appear to want is to use the attribute `first-of-type` to get the first `i`, which is in this case 26 Todman Ave Kensington.

**Edit:** I just saw that "26 Todman Ave Kensington" is not wrapped in the `i class="fa fa-map-marker`. Now your question has rendered me utterly confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to wrap the first line with a `<p>`tag. So you could select them by using `.pickup.ng-binding > p`

Comment: Or you could add a `<div id="this-is-the-todman-ave-address'>` element around it and style using the selector `#this-is-the-todman-ave-address`.

Comment: Code cannot be changed. we need to find a way to write a selector.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get one of the child text nodes inside `dd.pickup.ng-binding`, which is not in an `i` element but directly in the `dd` element. This cannot be achieved directly using just a CSS selector since selectors only look at element nodes, not text nodes. You *could* just select the `dd` itself like you have done, but you will need to `getText()` and then parse it and extract just the portion you need, which is cumbersome.

I recommend using XPath instead which allows you to select individual text nodes directly without having to worry about parsing what might be arbitrary text:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//dd[@class='pickup ng-binding']/text()[1]"));
```

Depending on what the actual markup looks like (what you have is a DOM tree view), if `text()[1]` doesn't get you anything it's probably inter-element whitespace; try `text()[2]` and so on until you find the text that you need.